# Representation of the symmetric group $ S_3$ in $3$ dimensions.

Tags: representation-theory

How to get a representation of the symmetric group $ S_3$ in $3$ dimensions?

Comment: You can take the direct sum of the trivial representation three times.

Comment: The representation of $S_3$ is likely to be in $R^2$ : see the representation of $S_n$ in $\R^{n-1}$ called permutohedron (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron).

Comment: Please be more specific. What properties do you want this representation to have?

Answer (score 1):

Others have already said this in the comments, but you can form a $3$-dimensional representation of $S_3$ by taking the direct sum (product) of three one dimensional representations. You might already know that if
$$
\pi: G \to GL(V) \\
\rho: G\to GL(W)
$$
are two representations of $G$, then you can define their direct sum 
$$
\pi\oplus\rho: G \to GL(V\oplus W)
$$
by
$$
(\pi\oplus\rho)(g)(v,w) = (\pi(g)v, \rho(g)(w))
$$
for $v\in V, w\in W$. The dimension of this representation is $\dim(V\oplus W) = \dim(V)+\dim(W)$.

To get your specific $3$-dimensional representation of $S_3$ just take three of the 1-dimensional representations. This could (as suggested above) just be the identity three times, or maybe you could try the sign representation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest and most interesting example of a three-dimensional representation of $S_3$ is by permuting basis vectors. Let $e_1, e_2, e_3$ be a basis of some three-dimensional vector space, then the rule $\sigma e_i = e_{\sigma(i)}$ for each $\sigma \in S_3$ defines a representation.

If you write this out in terms of matrices, you'll get the $3\times 3$ permutation matrices.